# Assign return value of DB2 query to variable

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, db2

I have a file test.sh in which i have a query which gives me the count of total records in the table, as shown below:

**Query**:

```
echo db2 -x "select count(*) from testable”
```

Now I want to assign the whatever value it returns after executing it to the variable as `totalRecords` using the Unix Shell Script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

cnt=`db2 -x "select count(*) from syscat.tables" `

echo "Counter is:  ${cnt}"
```

**Counter is:          474**

Comment: Thank you. Can i use this counter into some other files? If yes then how?

Comment: yes - you'd have to do a similar process of capturing the output with `` OR persist the value to a temp file and read the value into the script.